# naming redundancy in javascript function parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I set default value of timing param?

```
function active_timer(timing){
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        console.log('interval');
    }, timing);
}
```

I can do like this

```
function active_timer(timing){
    var time = 1000;
    if(timing){
        time = timing
    }
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        console.log('interval');
    }, time);
}
```

My problem is with the naming, timing and time actually are the same thing, how can I write less redundant code in javascript?

Comment: `interval = setInterval(function() { ... }, timing || 1000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An argument is a (local) variable just like any other.

```
timing = timing || 1000;
```

You can overwrite it without a care in the world.

Comment: why not a `var` in front?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a check in your function,

```
if (typeof timing == 'undefined')
    timing = defaultValue;
```

or ([ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator))

```
timing = (typeof timing == 'undefined') ? defaultValue : timing;
```

or

```
timing = timing || defaultValue
```

**Example `typeof`**

```
function x(y) 
{
  if (typeof y == 'undefined')
    y = 5;

  return y;
}

alert(x()); // 5

alert(x(25)); // 25
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pL98excx/)

**Reading Material**

[`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

[MDN - Default Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Answer (score 1):

**In ES2015 (aka "ES6") and later**, you can specify a default value for the argument:

```
// ES2015+
function active_timer(timing = 1000) {
// -------------------------^^^^^^^
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        console.log('interval');
    }, timing);
}
```

---

**In ES5 and earlier** *(well, technically all of this applies to ES2015+ as well)*: You can assign values to function arguments, so you don't need a separate variable unless you want one. If `active_timer` is called without any arguments, `timing` will have the value `undefined`.

You have a few options for how to determine you need to apply the default:

```
if (timing === undefined) {
    timing = 1000;
}
```

or

```
if (typeof timing === "undefined") {
    timing = 1000;
}
```

or

```
if (arguments.length === 0) {   // NOT RECOMMENDED
    timing = 1000;
}
```

*(Not recommended because using `arguments` within a function can impact its performance.)*

Or if you know `active_timer` will never be called with `0`, you can use the [curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html):

```
function active_timer(timing){
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        console.log('interval');
    }, timing || 1000); // Only if you know timing won't be 0
}
```

The result of `a || b` is the value of `a` if it' *truthy*, or the value of `b` if `a` is *falsy*. The falsy values are `0`, `""`, `undefined`, `null`, `NaN`, and of course, `false`.

Comment: Ah, that  last one is much better, didn't know it was possible (+1).

Comment: @Script47: Apologies, I just moved it so it's not the last one anymore. :-) Yup, great new feature as of ES2015.

Comment: How supported is ES6?

Comment: @Script47: In modern browsers, support is quite good these days (https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/). But because there are still people using obsolete browsers, most of us *transpile* ES2015 to ES5 using tools like [Babel](http://babeljs.io).

Comment: I found the ES6 `string.includes` function yesterday (slightly confused, thought it would be called `contains`...) and found it is supported in Chrome though not recognized in Webstorm(?), I may need to update it.

Comment: @Script47: The TC-39 committee make a real effort to avoid creating problems. In this case, there was a substantial buggy library in significant (though declining) use on the web which would have caused trouble if it had had the name `contains`. Same reason that ES2016's `Array#includes` isn't called `contains`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) and [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) of ES2015:

```
function activeTimer(timing = 1000) {
    setInterval( () => {
        console.log('interval:' + timing);
    }, timing);
}

activeTimer();
```

See also the [fiddle](http://www.es6fiddle.net/is3f09a0/).